# Problems making site not reload when tabs are accessed

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, dynamic

I'm trying to create a function that lets the user access the content of a clicked-on tab without having the page reload on them.

Initially, I thought that something like

```
$( "#tab1" ).click(function() {
    $("#content").load("tab1.html #content > *");
});
```

would work fine, but it doesn't - the page still reloads, thus leaving me stumped.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/otsfkMOeKA).

Does anyone see where my problem lies?

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-wrapper"> 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                   <li><a id="tab1" href="tab1.html">Tab1</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab2" href="tab2.html">Tab2</a></li>

                </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "container" -->
    </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->

<div class="container pad-container">
<div id="content">
         <h1>Content</h1>
         <p>stuff...</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
  </div>

    <div class="footer static-footer">
        <div class="container">             

        </div><!-- END: "container" --> 
    </div><!-- END: "footer static-footer" -->  
</div><!-- END: "container pad-container" -->
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
height:100%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.custom-wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
.pad-container{
padding-top:80px;
padding-bottom:80px; /*height of the footer plus a little */
}

.static-footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;   /* height of the footer */
background:#000000;
}
.static-footer .text-muted { /* text on left of footer */
color: #ffffff; 
margin-top: 17px;
}
.static-footer .text-primary{ 
margin-top: -33px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cancel the default click event:

```
$( "#tab1" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("tab1.html #content");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Now, clicking on Tab1 does absolutely nothing for me. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps your `load` is failing? Check the console, verify the URL is correct.

Comment: I have no idea how to debug this, because I can't find anything wrong. Hmm, is this functional using jquery 1.7.2?

Comment: Try `$("#content").load("tab1.html #content")` instead --  http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: This is weird - using jQuery 1.11.1 has made it work. However, I'm unable to tell whether it is in fact loading the content without reloading, as it still gives the "illusion" of reloading. Is there way a check if it is actually working?

Comment: The only problem I see is that you'll end up with two elements with the same ID.

Comment: @user3558931 wait, i think you're onto something. Care to elaborate please? Is this why when I click on the link, nothing happens?